# Extraigo una cadena desde un fichero y no se guarda bien el dato en la variable. Lenguaje C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

Este es el codigo donde tengo el error:

```
void insertarEstructuraCliente(ptroclientes **cliente)
{
    fopen_s(&archivo, "clientes.txt", "r");
    if (archivo)
    {
        fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END); \\veo si el archivo esta vacio
        if (ftell(archivo) != 0)   \\Si esta vacio, entra al while
            while (!feof(archivo))
            {
                char nombre[30];
                char cedula[20];
                fgets(nombre, 30, archivo);
                printf("\n\nPAUSA: %s\n\n", nombre); system("pause"); \\aqui imprime un monton de garabatos
                fgets(cedula, 20, archivo);
                int numCedula = atoi(cedula);
                insertarCliente(cliente, nombre, numCedula);
            }
        fclose(archivo);
    }
}
```

en la linea donde imprimo el valor de nombre, por pantalla me aparecen un monton de garabatos, como si no extrayera bien el dato desde el fichero.
Es un proyecto de C en visual studio 2017.

Comment: Nombre y cédula son variables locales del procedimiento, no se inicializan en ninguna parte del programa antes de la llamada a insertarEstructuraCliente, se supone que debería de inicializarse con gets y lo que esta guardado en el archivo, se supone que el procedimiento lee una línea del fichero y la primera línea de lo que lee lo guarda en la variable nombre, pero no se por que se embasura y me salen garabatos al momento de imprimir por pantalla lo que guarda

Comment: Me da la impresión de que el problema es que cuando lees estás al final del fichero porque has puesto el puntero al final para hacer esa comprobación que haces de si está vacío. Si no vuelves a posicionar el puntero ni compruebas los resultados de las lecturas, no se muy bien qué es lo que te estará leyendo. Posiblemente nada, y como no has inicializado ni nombre ni cedula, pues a saber lo que imprime. No hay caracter de finalización de cadena... No he probado tu código, pero tal vez el problema venga por ahí.

Comment: SuperG280 que crack hermano, muchas gracias, era eso, un error tonto que no me había dado cuenta, lo que hice fue cerrar el archivo y volverlo a abrir, aunque creo que poner el cursor al inicio es mas eficiente, pero resolví el problema, ya guarda los datos del fichero de texto bien, muchas gracias Dios te bendiga